# Does Mule supports Spring MVC?

Tags: spring-mvc, mule

I have web app which is already developed based on Spring MVC. I need to re-implement that web app in Mule.

1. Can I develop the mule application based on Spring MVC?
2. Can I declare the Spring MVC dispatcher servlet inside a mule's servlet endpoint and take things further from there?
3. The web app has web.xml where it defines the DispatcherServlet, the contextparams, the listener classes and so on. How can we remodel that in a mule application?
4. Any examples where a mule application is developed based on SpringMVC would be great.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to its embedded Jetty container, you can deploy any JavaEE web application in Mule. So there's no need to remodel anything.

The "Boosktore" example application demonstrates running web-apps within Mule: https://github.com/mulesoft/mule/tree/mule-3.x/examples/bookstore

Comment: Thanks for the reply. But I don't want to use the embedded Jetty container (reason is specific to my requirements.) In this case can you please help me with my queries which I have posted above?

Comment: Mule is not a JavaEE container so you can not use Spring MVC directly in a Mule application. Either embed a web-app in a Mule app and deploy on Mule Standalone OR create a standard web-app, embed Mule in it and deploy on a JavaEE container.

Comment: Thanks David for the reply.

Answer (score 0):

Mule ESB is not an MVC Framework. It is developed using [enterprise integration patterns](http://www.enterpriseintegrationpatterns.com/) in mind.

Please go through this [blog](http://blogs.mulesoft.org/to-esb-or-not-to-esb/), to know when to use ESB.

Answer (score 0):

spring mvc can be integrated with mule.

Define all your spring related configuration in separate xml file and include it in mule configuration  file.

You can write your custom transformers ,in the custom transformations you can inject or do an autowire of your service classes and from service object you can interact with dao layers.